# file transfer from local machine to unix

Tags: unix, web-deployment, file-transfer

Is there a way to transfer a file in local machine(Windows os) to a unix sever by using commands from within the unix server(not from the windows command prompt)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From within the unix server? Then you need to enable sharing on windows, be it SMB (easiest, but you need samba or smbfs on the unix server), FTP or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ssh on windows just install a software--putty.Or you can also directory winscp to transfer.
Note:unixe server must have installed ssh.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Filezilla to transfer files from Windows to Unix server .

http://filezilla-project.org/download.php